# Python skip header row from request response

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I’m querying a service to get csv data and I would like to append this csv extract to another file by skipping the header information 
Code -

```
response = requests.get('http://myservice.com&format=csv')
with open('out.csv', 'a', new like='') as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f)
   for line in response.iter_lines():
        next(line)
        writer.writerow(line.decode('utf-8').split('|'))
```

Tried the above but I get error

> ‘bytes’ object is not an iterator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
response = 
requests.get('http://myservice.com&format=csv')
with open('out.csv', 'a', new like='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    rows = response.iter_lines()
    next(rows)
    for line in rows:
        writer.writerow(line.decode('utf-8').split('|'))
```

`rows` is the iterator that needs to skip the header, whereas 
`line` is the actual content of each line read.

The `for` loop simply follows the iteration protocol, i.e.

- it obtains an iterator by calling `iter` on the object (an iterator returns itself, as in this case)
- it keeps calling `next` on it until the `StopIteration` exception is raised

Answer (score 4):

`response.iter_lines()` is the iterator, `lines` is the value from iterating. So calling `next()` on that doesn't make much sense.

You can:

```
iter_lines = response.iter_lines()
next(iter_lines, None)
for line in iter_lines:
    writer.writerow(line.decode('utf-8').split('|'))
```

You could also try reading straight into a `csv.DictReader`, e.g.:

```
response = requests.get('http://myservice.com&format=csv')
with open('out.csv', 'a') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(response.text.splitlines(), delimiter='|')
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, reader.fieldnames)
    writer.writerows(reader)
```